# Install SciPy in AWS Tensorflow instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, scipy

I'm completely hitting a brick wall. I'm trying to get SciPy installed o an AWS instance that is preconfigured with Tensorflow. The instance doesn't have the `apt-get` package manager, so I've been forced to use `pip`

So I've tried `udo /usr/local/bin/pip install scipy`

Note that I include the path because I somehow screwed up sudo access to `pip`

Then it throws this error first: `Failed building wheel for scipy`

Then it tries running `setup.py clean` and it throws this error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
e0UuQe/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record /tmp/pip-qKUiUV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
build-e0UuQe/scipy/
```

My AWS instance is running `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-28-195 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 24 01:31:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**UPDATE**

I have successfully installed SciPy, but when I run a python script with the module included it throws a `no module` error

Successfully installed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 ~]$ sudo yum install scipy
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-graphics/latest                                              | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-main/latest                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                               | 2.3 kB     00:00
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package python26-scipy-0.12.1-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 udacity]$ python assignment_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import ndimage
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Comment: Is your instance running AWS Linux? If so, it's based on RHEL and uses `yum` instead of `apt`.

Comment: @mtrw just updated post

Comment: try ``python2.6 assignment_1.py``