# `No module named SciPy` even though it is installed on AWS Tensorflow instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, module, scipy, yum

I'm running the AWS AMI instance that has tensorflow preinstalled. However, it did not come with SciPy, so I have had to install it. I have successfully installed it with `yum install scipy`

```
udacity]$ sudo yum install scipy
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package python26-scipy-0.12.1-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But then when I go to run the program I get this

```
$ python assignment_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import ndimage
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

This related to a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274002/install-scipy-in-aws-tensorflow-instance)

Python version is shown:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

**UPDATE**

SciPy was showing python2.6, so I have tried the following but am now getting an error about iPython even though I have it installed. Is it another version issue?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 udacity]$ sudo yum install ipython
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-graphics/latest                                              | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-main/latest                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                               | 2.3 kB     00:00
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package ipython available.
Error: Nothing to do
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 udacity]$ python2.6 assignment_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython.display import display, Image
ImportError: No module named IPython.display
```

Version:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-195 udacity]$ ipython --version
4.1.2
```

Comment: What's the result of `which python`?

Comment: @PeterWood updated post

Comment: `yum` says `python26-scipy` is installed, which won't show up on `2.7`.

Comment: @PeterWood you were right! now I'm getting an ipython error